# IValueConverter only being called when scrolling on DataGrid

Tags: wpf, xaml, ivalueconverter, multibinding

Take a look at the following XAML snippet:

```
<DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Block.TextAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Background">
            <Setter.Value>
                <SolidColorBrush>
                    <SolidColorBrush.Color>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource VAPBrushConverter}">
                            <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridCell}}"/>
                            <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}"/>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </SolidColorBrush.Color>
                </SolidColorBrush>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
```

The IValueConverter is being called *only* when I scroll on the datagrid. Inside the DataGridCell there is a TextBlock, and the only other time the IValueConverter is being called is when the TextBlock.Text property is DependencyProperty.UnsetValue.

Could someone tell me when the IValueConverter is called, and if there is something I can do with my code currently that could resolve this issue ? To clarify - the issue is that the background is only being set by the IValueConverter when I scroll on the DataGrid.

Comment: You're overcomplicating this with MultiBindings and Converters. Create a proper ViewModel for your rows and have some "easier" value to bind to or use `DataTriggers`.

Comment: @HighCore I understand what you're saying, but my ViewModels are being being converted to JSON directly for use in another API so I can't really add random properties just for my front end application. I could create some kind of decorator but I would prefer to use a converter for consistency.

Comment: @Sherlock that's really awkward. ViewModels are not data. If you need to send (JSON or whatever) to another API or application you should really serialize your MODELS, not ViewModels. ViewModels are precisely intended to be an intermediary between the Model and the UI (the same as converters, but cleaner, IMO)

Comment: Try for `DataGrid` set `ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"` for scrolls in terms of physical units. Maybe help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by setting the binding as the current element in the items source, like this:

```
<Binding Path="."/>
<Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}"/>
```

It looks like the problem is that the IValueConverter is only called when the get/set accessors are called. I was passing the DataGridCell in the binding which is only get/set when scrolling. The contents of the cell is get/set whenever the value changes, so this means the IValueConverter will update accordingly.